# Adding a row to an Excel Table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel worksheet (called Fee Planner - Standard Input) with a table on it (called StandardInput) and a button which calls a VBA Sub to add a new row to the bottom of the table:

```
Public Sub AddStandardInputRow()

    Dim standardInputTable As ListObject
    Dim newRow As ListRow

    Set standardInputTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fee Planner - Standard Input").ListObjects("StandardInput")
    Set newRow = standardInputTable.ListRows.Add

    Set standardInputTable = Nothing
End Sub
```

I seem to get random results from running this code, sometimes it works perfectly for a few rows and then starts to error, sometimes it errors from the first time the button is clicked. The errors thrown are

[image: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.]
followed by
[image: Application or object-defined error]
I only get the first error once, but after that I consistently get the 1004 error. SOmetimes I get the first error immediately after restarting Excel.

I'm guessing there's some underlying cause, but I can't see what it is.

Comment: This might sound obvious but are you 100% sure that the sheet name and table name haven't been changed/are correct?

Comment: is there any external source of ListObject data? what kind?

Comment: If you are using VBA to add/edit data, you don't need a ListObject unless you're pulling from an external source.  If you are, you shouldn't be adding to it by modifying the table.  Modify the source data and refresh.

Comment: do you know which line causes the error? Can you step debug a few times?

Comment: @Tom Yes, although I've got a colleague putting a second pair of eyes on it tomorrow so will get him to check that...

Comment: @KazJaw No, the ListObject is totally internal to the workbook

Comment: @TobyAllen It's the line that calls `...ListRows.Add`

Comment: @PhilPursglove Just for my own sanity could you replace `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(xxxx).ListObjects(xxxx)` with `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)` Just to see if it is a referencing issue (as long as you only have 1 table on the Active Worksheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the problems lie with the lines

```
Dim newRow As ListRow
...
Set newRow = standardInputTable.ListRows.Add
```

It appears there's a reference leak in that code on the `newRow` object.

I tried including a

```
Set newRow = Nothing
```

line on the penultimate line of the method which was better but still not great, I've now removed all reference to the `newRow` object completely so the method just calls `standardInputTable.ListRows.Add`, this seems to be much more reliable:

```
Public Sub AddStandardInputRow()

    Dim standardInputTable As ListObject

    Set standardInputTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fee Planner - Standard Input").ListObjects("StandardInput")
    standardInputTable.ListRows.Add

    Set standardInputTable = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use:

```
Sub M_snb()
  With Sheet1.ListObjects(1).Range
   sheet1.Cells(.Rows(.Rows.Count + 1).Row, .Columns(1).Column) = " "
  End With
End sub
```